# Merge two pandas dataframes with multiple columns per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a dataframe "df1" that look like this:

| company id | company name | dealid_1 | dealyear_1 | dealid_2 | dealyear_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | ABC |  |  |  |  |
| C2 | DEF |  |  |  |  |

Where I want to fill the blank cells with data from another dataframe "df2" which looks like this:

| deal id | deal year | company id | company name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 2010 | C1 | ABC |
| D2 | 2015 | C1 | ABC |
| D3 | 2012 | C2 | DEF |
| D4 | 2017 | C2 | DEF |

So the final result for "df1" should be as follows:

| company id | company name | dealid_1 | dealyear_1 | dealid_2 | dealyear_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | ABC | D1 | 2010 | D2 | 2015 |
| C2 | DEF | D3 | 2012 | D4 | 2017 |

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df3 = (df2.drop(columns='company name')
          .assign(col=df2.groupby('company name').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
          .pivot(index='company id', columns='col')
       )
df3.columns = df3.columns.map('_'.join)

out = df1[['company id', 'company name']].merge(df3, on='company id')
```

output:

```
  company id company name deal id_1 deal id_2  deal year_1  deal year_2
0         C1          ABC        D1        D2         2010         2015
1         C2          DEF        D3        D4         2012         2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with sorting second level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df3 = (df2.assign(g = df2.groupby(['company id','company name']).cumcount())
         .pivot(index=['company id','company name'], columns='g')
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df3.columns = df3.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1] + 1}')
print (df3.reset_index())
  company id company name deal id_1  deal year_1 deal id_2  deal year_2
0         C1          ABC        D1         2010        D2         2015
1         C2          DEF        D3         2012        D4         2017
```

For merge with first `df` use:

```
df = df1[['company id', 'company name']].join(df3, on=['company id', 'company name'])
```